# issues connecting MSI wind u123 via wireless

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, ndiswrapper, msi

Hello I own an MSI Wind u123

```
lspci output:
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller (rev 22)
lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co. Ltd. RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8199] (rev 22)
```

I've used ndisgtk successfully to install the windows 7 x86 driver. [realtek driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=40&PFid=40&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8187SE)
[image: ndisgtk dialog]
But for some reason I can't find the device in ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:21:63:35:3c  
      inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::224:21ff:fe63:353c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6142013 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:1266897 (1.2 MB)
      Interrupt:40 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:423576 (423.5 KB)  TX bytes:423576 (423.5 KB)
```

The output of `ifconfig -a` is identical as above. What can I do to fix this? Am I using ndiswrapper correctly?

Comment: Please amend your question to show: lspci -nn | grep 0280. I suspect a native Linux driver covers your device. Ndiswrapper uses XP drivers, not 7 or 8 or otherwise.

Comment: Could you try `sudo ifconfig -a`?

Comment: I will attempt to use the XP drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through these steps (it's ok if you've done some these before already, try them out anyway in this order):

In terminal:

1. Install ndiswrapper packages: `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils*`
2. Install the driver with `sudo ndiswrapper -i drivername.inf` from the folder where you have your windows driver files (`*.sys, *.inf`)
3. Install package `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms`
4. Check the driver installation with `ndiswrapper -l`, notice the driver name(s)
5. Do `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`
6. Check your `ìfconfig`. If the connection is listed, see number 7. If the wireless connection is not listed, try: `modprobe drivername` where drivername is the driver name result from number 4. If there are two of the names, run for both. Check your `ifconfig` in between.
7. If you got your connection listed, add `ndiswrapper` as a last line in your `\etc\modules` file (plus, as new lines, either of the two driver names from number 6 if needed). This way the driver will be loaded on system boot.

If you got your network listed, see your network manager if you can connect to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked! I made sure to install the driver from `/RT8187SE/WinXP/net8187Se.inf`. Output of `ndiswrapper -l` was `net8187se : driver installed device (10EC:8199) present (alternative driver: r8187se)`. This command `sudo modprobe r8187se` finally fixed it. Then added `r8187se` to the end of `/etc/modules`. Now I can connect to wireless on reboot. Seems like the chip is limited to 2g, can't join 5g networks. WPA2 Personal works. Make sure the hardware is on `fn + F11`.

Comment: Actually this probably means that you didn't even need ndiswrapper after all, but you just did not have r8187se module loaded. ;)